# Gzip for api response not working in dotnet

Tags: c#, .net

Hi i have used following code in my dotnet web api project to add gzip compression.
I am testing this from postman.
When i send header Accept-Encoding gzip, i get same response size and time as without gzip in header.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  // Add response compression
  services.AddResponseCompression(options => {
    options.EnableForHttps = true; // Enable compression for HTTPS requests
  });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) {
  // Enable response compression middleware
  app.UseResponseCompression();

  // Other middleware and routing configuration...

}
```

Also tested with chrome dev tools its same.
Its deployed on iis.
I am using dotnet 6.

I also added a custom middleware to use gzipstream but that seems to throw exception saying 'cannot acces closed stream'

```
public class ConditionalCompressionMiddleware {
  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
  public ConditionalCompressionMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
    _next = next;
  }

  public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {
    var response = context.Response;

    // Check if compression is allowed
    if (response.Headers.TryGetValue("allowCompression", out
        var allowCompressionHeader) &&
      bool.TryParse(allowCompressionHeader, out
        var allowCompression) &&
      allowCompression) {
      // Create a memory stream to buffer the response

      var originalBodyStream = response.Body;

      using
      var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

      response.Body = memoryStream;

      // Call the next middleware in the pipeline

      await _next(context);

      // Reset the memory stream position to the beginning

      memoryStream.Position = 0;

      // Enable response compression

      response.Headers["Content-Encoding"] = "gzip";

      // Wrap the memory stream with a gzip stream

      var compressedStream = new GZipStream(originalBodyStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal);

      await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(compressedStream);

      // Dispose the gzip stream and restore the original response stream

      compressedStream.Dispose();

      response.Body = originalBodyStream;
    } else {
      // Compression not allowed, call the next middleware in the pipeline
      await _next(context);
    }
  }
}
```